How to manually open a new tab in selenium python?
I want to manually make the selenium window open a new tab and open a url by searching it. I don't want to use JavaScript scripts to open it for my specific use case.
I tried to use ActionChains to open a new tab by sending Ctrl + t keys but it does not seem to work.
def manually_open_new_tab(url):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(url)


since the linked question doesn't mention it you should know that there is a new method for this in Selenium 4.x: driver.switch_to.new_window('tab'): https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/  It's a lot more convenient too since it opens the tab and switches the driver to it all in one line.
